# not able to compile code with "std::pair"

Tags: c++, c++11

I try to study and modify this program "https://github.com/PetterS/monte-carlo-tree-search.git" like this.

```
diff --git a/games/connect_four.h b/games/connect_four.h
index a575217..52f59cf 100644
--- a/games/connect_four.h
+++ b/games/connect_four.h
@@ -3,6 +3,7 @@

 #include <algorithm>
 #include <iostream>
+#include <utility>
 using namespace std;

 #include <mcts.h>
@@ -15,6 +16,9 @@ public:

        static const char player_markers[3]; 

+        typedef std::pair <int, int> MyMove;
+        static const MyMove my_no_move (-1, -1);
+
        ConnectFourState(int num_rows_ = 6, int num_cols_ = 7)
                : player_to_move(1),
              num_rows(num_rows_),
```

i.e., introduce a new type "MyMove" with std::pair and a constant. This code does not compile. If I remove those lines, it compiles with no problem.

```
.../monte-carlo-tree-search/games/connect_four.h:20:41: error: expected identifier before ‘-’ token
.../monte-carlo-tree-search/games/connect_four.h:20:41: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘-’ token
```

However, on the same machine, I test the same part of code which compiles.

```
#include <utility>

int main ()
{
    typedef std::pair <int, int> MyMove;
    static const MyMove my_no_move (-1, -1);
    return 0;
}

$ g++ temp.C -std=c++0x
$
```

Why? I admit the compiler on my machine is not updated which does not fully support c++11, but how come same lines of code have different result.

Comment: We dont even know what version your compiler is...

Comment: They have different results because they are not really the same lines of code; the first is an inlined member initialization, the second is a local variable declaration. They look identical but mean completely different things. Update your compiler.

Comment: Your testcase should have the two lines you're testing within a class definition, otherwise it's drastically different from the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare a member variable of a class like that.

Declare it as:

```
typedef std::pair <int, int> MyMove;
static const MyMove my_no_move;
```

And then define it outside the class as:

```
// The typedef MyMove is also scoped
const ConnectFourState::MyMove ConnectFourState::my_no_move(-1, -1);
```

Comment: Pardon me as a newbie of c++, but why this line works: "static const Move no_move = -1;" which is also inside class declaration? Maybe in my case the type is not simple enough for compiler to assign value? In addition, the error message sounds more like a syntax error which is even more confusing.

Comment: The line `static const Move no_move = -1;` can only compile if `Move` is a type that accepts a single integer value as input.  `std::pair` does not satisfy that.

Comment: If you are using C++11 or later, try this: `static const MyMove my_no_move{-1, -1};`

Answer (score 1):

You may do:

```
class MyClass {
    static const MyMove MyClass::my_no_move;
};

const MyMove MyClass::my_no_move(-1, -1);
```